# django testing wrapped function view with mock

Tags: python, django, testing, mocking

I am working through learning mock and I cannot figure out why this is not working...

```
@validate_captcha
def sendemail(request):
    ...
    email.send()
    return HttpResponse('Your email has been sent. Thank you for contacting us')
```

I have a wrapper that validates google recaptcha and I need to test this view but I cannot figure out how to get around the wrapper.

I tried this....

```
@patch('main.views.sendemail')
def test_sendmail_captcha_pass(self, mock_sendemail):
    """Testing the view after the captcha passing"""
    mock_sendemail.return_value = True
    things = Things()
    data = {
        'subject': 'test subject',
        'name': 'john appleseed',
        'email': 'john@apple.com',
        'content': 'content of the message'}

    post_url = reverse("main:contact_email")
    result = things.client.post(post_url, {})
    self.assertTrue(result.status_code == 401)
```

Since the sendemail function is already wrapped, I am using the sendemail function for `@patch` instead of the validate_captcha function but I cannot see what to do next.

I have tried making a mock object in the shell and verified that it does indeed give a a wrapped version of the sendemail function